# Scripts in mvc blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I started with an mostly empty project: [Empty WebAPI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615805/Creating-a-Clean-Minimal-Footprint-ASP-NET-WebAPI)
the project has grown a bit, and now I need to have 1 layouted page.

**Things added for that page:**

Added controller named: StreamController

Added a `/Views/Stream/Details.cshtml` file.

the web.config and in `/Views` there is another web.config containing:

`<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />`
And added it's reference.

added `/Scripts` folder and added my scripts

Added a BundleConfig and RouteConfig (just copied them from an Asp.net WebApi project that was generated from the standard project creation.

Added my bundles to the BundleConfig

Added the config's in `Global.asax`.

**Problem:**

When I go to a `/Scripts/xxx.js` it return blank.

Am I forgetting a config ? or something?

Comment: Try `/Scripts/xxx.js`

Comment: @MrZapzup: was typo in post. but good catch.

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong in my web.config. I updated my `system.webServer` tot the following and it works now.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```